# Multiple projects using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, webserver

I recently installed Laravel and created a project on my webserver. I had to create a symbolic link for public_html to the public folder inside the Laravel folder. I realized that if I wanted to create another project, how would I do that?

I used to use CodeIgniter and setup was just placing it in a folder and typing the www.url.com/project1
www.url.com/project2 
to access the different projects

Comment: You can use laravel modules, each module have its own controller, routes, views. For more info xfer: https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v1/introduction

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering. It's a little strange that I would have to use an external package to get this to work? Are there any other ways?

Comment: Can you configure the server? You can probably use an alias in the config instead of a symlink to the configured document root, or configure rewrites.

Comment: Hi yes I can configure the server

Answer (score 4):

Basically each laravel installation comes with a public folder. The public folder contains the `index.php` file, which is the entry point for all requests entering your application. This directory also houses your assets such as images, `JavaScript`, and `CSS`.

If you want to put laravel on sub directory, you will have access to sub directory's public folder. For example, `www.url.com/project2/public`

But a better solution of this is to create a sub domain and point the directory path to `public_html/project2/public` so you will have a working laravel on URL like this, `www.project2.url.com`

This is shared hosting solution and works for all laravel versions.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Does this mean I will have to create a subdomain for each project? I'm worried because it seems quite a long process. If I create a sub directory, how would the structure be like? Laravel -> public -> project1 -> public -> index.php ?

Comment: Would it be possible to just create a public_html and the create my laravel projects inside it. So the structure will be like public_html -> project1 and public_html-> project2

Comment: Yes indeed. Supposing each project folder has laravel installation so each folder's public folder will be your root of application on web.